# Logback + GlassFish: How to log everything to console but only app specific messages to a different log file

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3, slf4j, logback

I have a web application which is deployed on GlassFish 3.1.1. The current situation is that all log statements, means the ones from GlassFish and the ones from my application, are written into `server.log` of GlassFish.

I need a configuration which separates the logging, so that it logs to two different files, one for GlassFish (`server.log`) and one for my application (`application.log`).

I tried the following:

I added this to my `domain.xml`:

```
<jvm-options>-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/_logging.properties</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/logback.xml</jvm-options>
```

This is my `logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %class:%L - %m%ex</pattern>
  </encoder>
 </appender>

 <appender name="defaultLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file>application.log</file>
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %F - %m%n%ex</pattern>
   </encoder>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
     <fileNamePattern>application.%i{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
     <MaxFileSize>5MB</MaxFileSize>
   </triggeringPolicy>
 </appender>

 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
   <appender-ref ref="defaultLog"/>
 </root>
</configuration>
```

and this is the `_logging.properties`:

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=true
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.alarms=false
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
```

The original `logging.properties` which was included in GlassFish is at its initial state.

I log messages like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Stub {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Stub.class);

    public void test() {
        logger.info("hello");
    }
}
```

Now, with this configuration I have the following situation:

- all log statements are printed in the NetBeans console
- the log statements from my application are logged to `application.log`
- the log statements from my application are additionally logged to `server.log`
- the log statements from GlassFish are logged to `server.log`

Nearly what I want, but this obviously creates some redundancy and isn't a proper solution for the goal (separate the logging).

If I remove the `ConsoleAppender` from the `logback.xml` so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <appender name="defaultLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file>application.log</file>
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %class - %m%n%ex</pattern>
   </encoder>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
     <fileNamePattern>application.%i{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
     <MaxFileSize>5KB</MaxFileSize>
   </triggeringPolicy>
 </appender>

 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
   <appender-ref ref="defaultLog"/>
 </root>
</configuration>
```

then I have only GlassFish specific log messages in `server.log` and only application error messages in `application.log`, but the application log messages do not appear in the NetBeans console (because they are not appended to the console obviously).

I don't really get how this is working in general, so one question is, **why does it (partially) work this way? How does `logback` know that only the application specific messages should be logged into `application.log`? Why are the GlassFish messages not logged into `application.log`?**

I suspect that GlassFish logs his stuff in a different way? I guess I have to somehow change the configuration of the normal GlassFish logging, but I don't have a clue how. I tried setting the log level for my application packages to OFF in the normal `logging.properties` but this doesn't change anything, I guess this is because the log messages look like this:

```
[#|2014-05-23T16:43:02.948+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|23 Mai 2014 16:43:02.947 INFO  com.test.MyInitializer - [Module initialized]|#]
```

It looks like it can't filter the messages because they come from `javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging`, but if I filter this package, the log messages are not logged in the console.

My main question: How to fix the issue, **how to log only application specific messages to a different log file, all GlassFish log messages to `server.log` and really ALL log messages to the console?**

Comment: Have you solved your problem?  Ihave a similar one and I don't find anything about it.

Comment: No I haven't solved it :(

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was so happy with tomcat till I was asked to port servlets to glassfish. Good luck!